# How can I use array variable in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var n = new Array();
n[0] = "zero";
n[1] = "first";
n[2] = "second"

function myFunction() {
    var x = prompt("Question?")
    if (x.toLowerCase() == n) {
        //code
    } else {
        //code
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make it so that if any of the array variables are typed in, the if / else function is still carried out.

Comment: The question isn't clear

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What *are* you trying to do? You can't compare a string to an array like that.

Comment: sorry. really struggling to phrase things here. basically, if anyone types in the array values ("zero", "first"...), can the if or else statements be carried out. if `(x..==n)` just makes it so that when the letter "n" is typed into the prompt box the statements are carried out.

Comment: @LiamB Actually, `x.toLowerCase() == n` will not be true when the letter `n` is typed into the input box. `n` is an array of the strings `"zero", "first", "second"`, and is not equal to the string `"n"`. Just to recap, `n` is an array, `x.toLowerCase()` is a string that contains the lowercased input. You are checking whether a string equals an array, which is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm *guessing* you want to check if the typed value exists in the array? If so:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = prompt("Question?")
    if (n.indexOf(x.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        //code
    } else {
        //code
    }
}
```

You you need to support IE8 and earlier, you'll need a shim for Array.prototype.indexOf (for example, [the one provided by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)).

Comment: +1, You're on a roll today. I can barely get a word in edgewise.

Comment: The indexOf() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier. Consider looping through the array or use one from a js library

Comment: thanks. the code works and you managed to understand my poorly phrased question. +1

Comment: @sshen That's true, added a link to an example shim.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you want the condition to be true on every array element or just on at least one, you can use [n.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [n.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = new Array();
n[0] = "zero";
n[1] = "first";
n[2] = "second"

function myFunction()
{
var x=prompt("Question?")
    for (var i in n) {
        if (x.toLowerCase() === n[i] ){ alert("true"); }  
    }
}

myFunction();
```